# wos2 active-active all in one config load balancer with IIS not NGINX

Tags: nginx, iis, wso2, load-balancing, wso2-api-manager

I have 3 services. One service is for wso2 database. I am using wso2 pattern 2 (active-active all in one) so I have wso2-am 2.6.0 and wso2-am-analytics 2.6.0 in both remained services. I want these two services work active-active.
I configure my services according to [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment#ConfiguringanActive-ActiveDeployment-step1Step1-CreateaSSLcertificate) .in part2 configure load balancer: I don't want to use NGINX and I want to use IIS. I try to config IIS in my local according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing) . So I define two services (IP of my services) in service frim of IIS. I am not sure that I config right and I don't know how test it. how host names of wso2 set in IIS?
Is it possible to use IIS instead of NGINX for load balance support in wso2?

Comment: Technically it doesn't matter what proxy (or load balancer) are you using. Until your proxy does the job (proxy requests, for publisher and store you need sticky session and host header).   (I am not good with IIS so I won't provide much details)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can use IIS load balancer between my other servers but still has problem with wso2 servers. so I decided to use hardware load balancer.